# Extract part of a video using ffmpeg_extract_subclip - black frames

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use: **"ffmpeg_extract_subclip"** for extracting  part of a video.

And I'm facing a few problems:

1.when I'm cutting a small video (1-3seconds) I'm getting black frames, only audio is working.
2.when I'm cutting longer video, the output video is stuck 2-3 seconds before the end.

This is my simple code:

```py
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip

input_video_path = 'myPath/vid1.mp4'
output_video_path = 'myPath/output/vid1.mp4'
t1 = 6.5
t2 = 16    # random numbers, my last attempt..
    
ffmpeg_extract_subclip(input_video_path, t1, t2, targetname=output_video_path)
```

I tried to look inside the code:
[ffmpeg_extract_subclip Function](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_tools.py#L27)

But still couldn't understand what's wrong.. :(

I'm still trying, and if anyone knows the problem or have a different approach, that will be amazing.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try to use `moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip`:

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip

input_video_path = 'myPath/vid1.mp4'
output_video_path = 'myPath/output/vid1.mp4'

with VideoFileClip(input_video_path) as video:
    new = video.subclip(t1, t2)
    new.write_videofile(output_video_path, audio_codec='aac')
```

It works fine for me. `aah` audio codec is important for Safari and some Mac OS video players.

Comment: checked it, and it's great! Thanks!

Comment: ffmpeg_extract_subclip is alot faster than video.subclip.
why ffmpeg_extract_subclip shouldn't work ?!!

Comment: How does this play with mkv?

Comment: Had the same problem. This worked for me! Thanks and I didn't see significant speed reduction. If anyone could solve the issue and still use ffmpeg_extract_subclip that would be great!

Comment: This method reencodes video, reducing its quality. Needless

Comment: Wow, this code really did work flawlessly. The sound in my previous example was problematic. I appreciate you sharing this so much.

Answer (score 8):

There's a fix in the master for moviepy [here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_tools.py#L27) however it's yet to update to the pip index. So what I used the code below to bring it into my program

```
from moviepy.tools import subprocess_call
from moviepy.config import get_setting

def ffmpeg_extract_subclip(filename, t1, t2, targetname=None):
    """ Makes a new video file playing video file ``filename`` between
    the times ``t1`` and ``t2``. """
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if not targetname:
        T1, T2 = [int(1000*t) for t in [t1, t2]]
        targetname = "%sSUB%d_%d.%s" % (name, T1, T2, ext)

    cmd = [get_setting("FFMPEG_BINARY"),"-y",
           "-ss", "%0.2f"%t1,
           "-i", filename,
           "-t", "%0.2f"%(t2-t1),
           "-vcodec", "copy", "-acodec", "copy", targetname]

    subprocess_call(cmd)
```

you can then call is as a normal function. 
*This requires that you have moviepy and it's dependencies already installed*

Comment: Thanks,  this really worked. BTW do u know why they haven't updated the pip index?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Straight forward and works great!