# Extract part of a video using ffmpeg_extract_subclip - get a clip longer than expected

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing, moviepy

I'm trying to extract a part of a video and find the solution on this page very helpful: 
[Extract part of a video using ffmpeg_extract_subclip - black frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257731/extract-part-of-a-video-using-ffmpeg-extract-subclip-black-frames)

The function `write_videofile` helps get what I need exactly but a bit slow. The `ffmpeg_extract_subclip` function is indeed very fast, but somehow generates a weird clip that is slightly longer than what I need. For example, if I use the `cmd` below (no matter with or without `-copyinkf`),

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 218.00 -i input.mp4 -t 7.00 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
```

My output.mp4 will be 9 second long, with the last two seconds frozen with no audio. Anyone saw a similar issue before? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking help? It may be an issue with input vs output seeking?

Comment: add start and end time both for a subclip

Comment: The issue is still there when using "ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i input.mp4 -to 00:00:15 -c copy output.mp4". The end time is 00:00:16 with the last second a frozen subclip of the last frame at 00:00:15. Are you also seeing similar issue? Or it is due to my ffmpeg version (4.2.3 on ios)?

Comment: I find that removing "-vcodec copy -acodec copy" helps so the reason may be related to the encoding step behind. After allowing encoding, the speed becomes as slow as "write_videofile". Seems a trade-off